# Roadmap for beginners developers

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, development

I am Brazilian and would like to program functionality for Bitcoin and LN. But I have no knowledge of programming and am lost as to what to study. Could you help me?
What do you recommend?

*i do know nothing about programming.

Answer (score 2):

> I have no knowledge of programming ... What do you recommend?

If you are an adult, evening-classes in programming at your nearest educational establishment (school etc).

If you are not an adult and are in full time education, I would ask a teacher to suggest courses inside or outside school. In many countries, schools have courses that are relevant,

You could also contact a professional body. For example, in the UK, you could contact https://bcs.org.

Answer (score 0):

- Learn python with online resources.

  <sup>https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python</sup>

  <sup>https://github.com/quobit/awesome-python-in-education</sup>
- Run a bitcoin node, use signet and try different things. Search online or ask questions if you don't understand something.

  <sup>https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/</sup>
- Try to solve the problems you see or read bitcoin core issues and comments in pull requests. Stackoverflow, Subreddits and lot of forums could help you with the syntax and sometimes other things but developing a coding logic is more important.

  <sup>https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/</sup>